Why is texture painting not working?
Please advise-
I've watched a few different tutorials for texture painting but I'm not sure what I'm still doing wrong. Texture painting is not working. I'm trying to add an orange/red color over the yellow shape but nothing is happening. 

Hello could you please pack your images and share your file so that we can give a try?

I apologize, I'm so new to this that I don't quite know what you're asking for or how to do that. Could you explain? Otherwise I can look up how to pack images and share my file.

Do a File > External Data > Pack Resources, then share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ (read instructions) or another platform like workupload

Thank you! I'll do that in a bit.



Close the texture you've selected:

Also note that you've enabled the Stabilize Stroke option:


It works now. Thank you!!

Just so I know for future projects- why did I need to close out of the texture I created?

You were just painting black (your texture) on the surface, not the desired color

Got it, thank you!
